# Where are Knowledge Article attached files stored?

Tags: apex, soql, attachment, knowledge

[image: File attached to Knowledge Article]

I've created custom field of "File" type with name "Attachment" and added image to one of Knowledge Articles(see screenshot). After that I've checked Attachment, ContentVersion, ContentDocument objects and couldn't find it there.
Can someone advice where this attachment can be stored and how I can get it via SOQL?

Answer (score 1):

This file is part of your knowledge article object, i.e. **[ArticleType]_kav** object that you might have. So it is stored in that particular object against the custom field `Attachment__c` that you created.

You have four fields created against **file** type field, since it is a compound field, in the **articleType__kav** object. **__kav** represents knowledgeArticleVersion, to query the file record in the above object, you need to write following soql

```
SELECT id, Attachment__Name__s, Attachment__ContentType__s, Attachment__Length__s, Attachment__Body__s  
FROM ArticleType__kav
```

Where, `Attachment` is your field name.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the attachment (which is your custom field under articletype__kav) you would simply have to query for it as you would any other custom field under your object,

for example:

```
SELECT **Fields** from articletype__kav.
```

Please refer to [Introduction to SOQL and SOSL](http://Salesforce%20Object%20Query%20Language%20(SOQL)) for future reference.